# Как сделать обновление страницы после нажатия кнопки удаления товара с корзины?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть копка удаления, через onclick происходит удаление

```
<button type="button" class="lii" name="del" onclick="window.location.href='/cart?id='+<?php echo $value->id ?>"> удалить</button>
```

Сделал скрипт на обновление страницы

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".lii").click(function func(){
    location.reload();
    return true;
});
setTimeout(func, 1000);
```

Ну и нифига не работает. Наверно из-за onclick. Что посоветуете ? Просто при удалении товар висит пока не удалю 2-рой товар или не перегружу страницу. Удаление товара с корзины jQuery и Ajax я еще не умею.

Comment: попробуй удалить название функции и ничего не возвращать, просто оставь `location.reload();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Если правильно тебя понял.**

Измени свой код на вот такой

Убираешь онклик, а создаешь дата атрибут (какой хочешь, в данном случае **id**)

```
<button type="button" class="lii" name="del" data-id="<?=$value->id;?>">удалить</button>
```

А скрипт меняешь вот на такой. На элемент с классом **.lii** навешивается отслеживание события **click**, после чего происходит аякс запрос на твою страничку **/cart** c **GET** / **id**

```
 $('.lii').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
           url:'/cart',
           data:{id:$(this).data('id')},
           success:function(){
              location.reload();
           }
        });
    });
```

После выполнения аякса - страница перезагрузится

Comment: Спасибо. Нужно все таки заняться изучением jquery и ajax